# How do I use a for loop to repeat this input?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having some difficulty understanding for loops. I need this input to be asked 4 times and the output to be shown 4 times as well.

```
# Take user input
coin_side = input('Heads or Tails ? Type H or T > ')
coin_side = coin_side.upper()

# Generate random number for players
player_1 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
player_2 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])

print('Player 1 has tossed ', player_1)
print('Player 2 has tossed ', player_2)

if coin_side == player_1:
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif coin_side == player_2:
    print('Player 2 wins')
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried `for _ in range(4): ...`?

Comment: I have tried using for _ range(4) right now but I am very new at python and don't understand what it means. @0x5453

Comment: You also have an issue with the `if` / `elif` part. If both players win you will print only the victory message for `player1` - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the for loop:

```
for _ in range(4):
    # Take user input
    coin_side = input('Heads or Tails ? Type H or T > ')
    coin_side = coin_side.upper()

    # Generate random number for players
    player_1 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])
    player_2 = random.choice(['H', 'T'])

    print('Player 1 has tossed ', player_1)
    print('Player 2 has tossed ', player_2)

    if coin_side == player_1:
        print('Player 1 wins')
    elif coin_side == player_2:
        print('Player 2 wins')
```

As you said that you're beggining I'll try to break it to you.

For loop syntax looks like this `for part in all_:`. To this syntax work, the `all_` part should be iterable. So for each iteration you will have one piece of the `all_` denoated by `part` that you can work with inside the for loop.

The function `range` returns a range from 0 to `n-1`, being `n` the number that you passed as parameter to the range function.

I won't go deeper into it, but the function range returns a range that is a immutable sequence type. But for the sake of simplicity you can imagine it as list for this example.

So using `range(4)` would return `0, 1, 2, 3` that are 4 numbers, making using `for _ in range(4)` iterate 4 times over the code that is inside the loop.

You may have noticed that we are using underscore as the variable on this for loop, this happens because as convention we use underscore when we won't use it inside the for loop.

You may face a situation in the future where you will need the value you are iterate over, so the for loop would look like this `foor n in range(4)` or `for customer in customers`